# Crystal lang curried

Tags: crystal-lang

I try to create curried add proc in Crystal. How make this example to work?

```
semi_curry = ->(f: Proc(Int32, Int32)) { ->(a: Int32) { ->(b: Int32) { f.call(a, b) } } }

add = ->(a: Int32, b: Int32) {a + b}

p semi_curry(add).call(5).call(6)
```

https://play.crystal-lang.org/#/r/3r0g

I get error

no overload matches 'Proc(Int32, Int32)#call' with types Int32, Int32
Overloads are:
 - Proc(T, R)#call(*args : *T)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [the proc documentation](https://crystal-lang.org/docs/syntax_and_semantics/literals/proc.html), `Proc(Int32, Int32)` is a proc that takes one `Int32` and returns one `Int32`. You mean to use `Proc(Int32, Int32, Int32)`. Also, you need to use `semi_curry.call(add).call(5).call(6)`.

```
semi_curry = ->(f: Proc(Int32, Int32, Int32)) { ->(a: Int32) { ->(b: Int32) { f.call(a, b) } } }

add = ->(a: Int32, b: Int32) {a + b}

p semi_curry.call(add).call(5).call(6)
```

https://play.crystal-lang.org/#/r/3r0m

If you're looking to curry a proc in your application, instead of as a learning exercise, you should use [`Proc#partial`](https://crystal-lang.org/api/latest/Proc.html#partial%28%2Aargs%3A%2AU%29forallU-instance-method) instead.